# Max Value always setting to 8

Tags: c

I was writing a program that takes the input, and then prints the maximum value of the frequency of each letter in it. For this program, I have decided to take the input only as these 5 letters: a,b,c,d and e. The program goes like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i, c , nchar[5];
    int maxvalue;

   for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    nchar[i]=0;
   }

    /*COLLECTING AND SETTING THE DATA*/
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        if (c=='a')
            nchar[0]++;

        else if (c=='b')
            nchar[1]++;

        else if (c=='c')
            nchar[2]++;

        else if (c=='d')
            nchar[3]++;

        else if (c=='e')
            nchar[4]++;

    }
    printf("%d",setMax(nchar,maxvalue));


}
int setMax(int a[5], int maxv){
    if ( a[0]> a[1] &&  a[0]> a[2] &&  a[0]>a[3] &&  a[0]> a[4])
        a[0]=maxv;

    else if ( a[1]> a[0] && a[1]> a[2] && a[1]> a[3] && a[1]> a[4])
        a[1]=maxv;

    else if ( a[2]> a[0] && a[2]> a[1] && a[2]> a[3] && a[2]> a[4])
        a[2]=maxv;

    else if ( a[3]> a[0] && a[3]> a[2] && a[3]> a[1] && a[3]> a[4])
        a[3]=maxv;

    else if ( a[4]> a[0] && a[4]> a[2] && a[4]> a[3] && a[4]> a[1])
        a[4]=maxv;

        return maxv;

}
```

Now, for example I write the input as 'aaabc', it should print the value 3 because the maximum frequency is of letter 'a' which is 3. But, it is printing the value 8. Not only this input, but anything I write as input, it always prints 8. Can someone tell me what mistake have I done?

Comment: Now can you imagine if you had to do all 26 letters?  26 else-if's, 26 comparisons, etc.  Of course there is a much shorter way to do this exercise.

Comment: Thats not the point right now. I was just writing the function setMax() to test whether the code is correct or not.

Comment: BTW: That entire while loop is 2 lines of code.  `while((c=getchar())!=EOF){ if ( c >= 'a' and c <= 'e' ) nchar[c - 'a']++; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your logic backward.

Instead of

```
if ( a[0]> a[1] &&  a[0]> a[2] &&  a[0]>a[3] &&  a[0]> a[4])
    a[0]=maxv;
```

you need

```
if ( a[0]> a[1] &&  a[0]> a[2] &&  a[0]>a[3] &&  a[0]> a[4])
    maxv = a[0];
```

**General Improvement**

Change the name of the function `setMax()` to `getMax()` and change its signature to:

```
int getMax(int a[5]);
```

Change the usage to:

```
printf("%d", getMax(nchar);
```

And change the implementation to:

```
int getMax(int a[5]){

   int maxv = 0;
    if ( a[0]> a[1] && a[0]> a[2] &&  a[0]>a[3] &&  a[0]> a[4])
        maxv = a[0];

    else if ( a[1]> a[0] && a[1]> a[2] && a[1]> a[3] && a[1]> a[4])
        maxv = a[1];

    else if ( a[2]> a[0] && a[2]> a[1] && a[2]> a[3] && a[2]> a[4])
        maxv = a[2];

    else if ( a[3]> a[0] && a[3]> a[2] && a[3]> a[1] && a[3]> a[4])
        maxv = a[3];

    else if ( a[4]> a[0] && a[4]> a[2] && a[4]> a[3] && a[4]> a[1])
        maxv = a[4];

    return maxv;
}
```

**Update**

An updated version of `getMax()` that fixes the problem when two values are equal.

```
int getMax(int a[5])
{
   if ( a[0] >= a[1] && a[0] >= a[2] &&  a[0] >= a[3] &&  a[0] >= a[4] )
      return a[0];

   // a[0] is not the max. it has has be a[1], a[2], a[3], or a[4]
   if ( a[1] >= a[2] && a[1] >= a[3] && a[1] >= a[4] )
      return a[1];

   // Similarly, the max has to be a[2], a[3], or a[4]
   if ( a[2] >= a[3] && a[2] >= a[4] )
      return a[2];

   // Similarly, the max has to be a[3] or a[4]
   if ( a[3] >= a[4] )
      return a[3];

   // At this point, a[4] has to be the max value.
   return a[4];
}
```

Comment: That worked... But can you explain 1 last thing.... Instead of a[0] = maxv, why we should write maxv = a[0]??

Comment: @Siddhant, when you use `a[0] = maxv;`, the value of `maxv` is assigned to `a[0]`. When you use `maxv = a[0];`, the value of `a[0]` is assigned to `maxv`.

Comment: @Siddhant This does not work. It is an invalid code.

Comment: @R Sahu  The function is not valid in case when there are equal values.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Absolutely correct. Added an update.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I saw that but the updated logic is not correct.

Comment: @R Sahu  Why do you think so?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I take my previous statement back. The updated version is good. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

do `maxval = 0` and just return a[0] a[1] etc which ever condition is satisfied. Dont assign the value to maxval.

Or if you want to do like this, Here is the code for `setMax()` func:

```
int setMax(int a[5], int maxv){

int i=0;
maxval = a[0];
for (i=1;i<5;i++)
 if (maxval < a[i])
  maxval = a[i];
return maxval;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `maxvalue` has an undefined value when you call `setMax()`.

This gives undefined behavior.

Also I don't think `setMax()` makes sense. I think it should do `return a[0]` in the first `if`, and so on.

Comment: I just declared the variable maxvalue with value 0. But then it is printing the value '0'.

Comment: @Siddhant Read the rest of my answer. Those `a[0] = maxvalue;` assignments make no sense. Should *perhaps* be `maxvalue = a[0]`, or `maxvalue = 0;`, or just `return 0;` and so on. Drop `maxvalue` as an argument to the function, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `maxvalue` is uninitialized, and it's value will be indeterminate. Using it in calculations will lead to undefined behavior.

Besides, you *always* return it (or rather `maxv`) from the `setMax` function *without modifications*, so you will always print the same value.

Comment: So while declaration of maxvalue, what value should I assign to it(coz when I assign the value of '0' to it, then the printed value is '0')

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed my Mr. Unwind and Mr. JP, the usage of `maxvalue` in current code invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're using an uninitialized automatic variable value.

Based on the usage of `setMax()` function in your code, I think, what you want to do is (are)

- **Point 1** You don't need to define `maxvalue` in `main()` and pass that as a parameter to `setMax()`.
- **Point 2** Inside `setMax()` function, define a local `maxvalue` and change `a[0]=maxv;` and series to `maxv = a[0];` and likewise.